# Value is False and the condition is -eq $true in if statement and it pass

Tags: powershell

I'm newbie with powershell. I am always learning about, and I started last Friday. So forgive me if it's obvious!
I don't why the first if statement pass whereas the condition is not respected.

I'm trying to check if a program is running on my computer. If yes, it's telling me "Programme is running" ! And when it's not running anymore, it write that is not running.
There is my code :

```
if (isPrgmRunning -eq $true) {
    isPrgmRunning #Return false, why the last if statement pass ???
    write-output "Programme is running"
    $isRunning = $true 
    while($isRunning) {
        write-output "While the programme keep running"
        if(CheckInternetConnection) {
            if(isPrgmRunning -eq $false) {
                isPrgmRunning #Check again value, and it's false
                Write-Output "If it's not running anymore"
                $isRunning = $false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it's not running and the first if pass...

There is all the scrpit :

```
$global:previousStatus=$null

# Function to check if the computer is connected to the internet
Function CheckInternetConnection {
    $currentStatus = Test-Connection -ComputerName "www.google.com" -Count 1 -Quiet
    If ($currentStatus -ne $global:previousStatus) {
        If ($currentStatus) {
            ShowMessageBox "Connected"
        }
        Else {
            ShowMessageBox "Disconnected"
        }
        $global:previousStatus = $currentStatus
    }
    return $currentStatus
}


# Function to display a message box
Function ShowMessageBox {
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($args[0], "Internet Connection Status")
}

# Function to check if the "Minecraft" program is running can be replace by any other
Function isPrgmRunning {
    try {
        $process = Get-Process -Name "Minecraft" -ErrorAction Stop #This is an exemple of programme :)
        if ($process -ne $null) {
            write-output "Prgm run"
            return $true
        }
    } catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException] {
        write-output "Prgm not run"
        return $false
    }
}

# Main function
function Main {
    while($true){
        if (CheckInternetConnection) {
        write-output "Connected"
            if (isPrgmRunning -eq $true) {
                isPrgmRunning #Return false, why the last if statement pass ???
                write-output "Programme is running"
                $isRunning = $true 
                while($isRunning) {
                    write-output "While the programme keep running"
                    if(CheckInternetConnection) {
                        if(isPrgmRunning -eq $false) {
                            isPrgmRunning #Check again value, and it's false
                            Write-Output "If it's not running anymore"
                            $isRunning = $false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

Main
```

Thank you for any help on my script ! I'll hear all advice and solution that you can send me !

**[Edit]**: Problem solved. It was on isPrgmRunning. I don't know why but instead of this :

```
$process = Get-Process -Name "Minecraft" -ErrorAction Stop
```

I've take this on educba.com/powershell-boolean/ :

```
Get-Process | where{$_.Name -eq "Wrong process"} -ErrorAction Ignore
```

So we get this :

```
Function isPrgmRunning {
    $process = Get-Process | where{$_.Name -eq "Minecraft"} -ErrorAction Ignore #Still with Minecraft but it can be "Teams" or something else
    if($process){
        return $true
    }
    else{
        return $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate the function, at the moment you're just checking if it exists, Try it this way:

```
$checkinternetconnection = $true

Function isPrgmRunning {
    try {
        $process = Get-Process -Name "Teams" -ErrorAction Stop #This is an exemple of programme :)
        if ($process -ne $null) {
            write-output "Prgm run"
            return $true
        }
    } catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ProcessCommandException] {
        write-output "Prgm not run"
        return $false
    }
}


function Main {
    while($true){
        if ($CheckInternetConnection) {
        write-output "Connected"
            if (isPrgmRunning) {
                isPrgmRunning #Return false, why the last if statement pass ???
                write-output "Programme is running"
                $isRunning = $true 
                while($isRunning) {
                    write-output "While the programme keep running"
                    if($CheckInternetConnection) {
                        if(!(isPrgmRunning)) {
                            isPrgmRunning #Check again value, and it's false
                            Write-Output "If it's not running anymore"
                            $isRunning = $false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}
main
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! But it's still the same, I don't know why the first if (isPrgmRunning) {} pass. In the output, it's still false...

Comment: Revised script works for me....

Comment: I have copy your script on a new script then paste it. I swear that it didn't work. It's unbelievable...

Comment: Problem solved, see above my edit. Thank you for your time and advice !